# Can't fix 'bundle install' failing for gems with native extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I am deploying Ruby On Rails apps on an Amazon EC2 cloud server. The server is running on Amazon Linux alami-2011.02. I can't say the distro it's based on (from my search, RedHat/CentOS, but I'm newbie in that field).

I've installed my Ruby environment with RVM (installed as root). I've setup two rubies:

- REE 1.8.7
- Ruby 1.9.2-p290

For each Rails app I deploy, I create a separate RVM gemset.

Since I ran in this problem, I've refreshed completely the Ruby environment by running `rvm implode`.

Here are my environment versions:

```
ruby -v      ---> ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]
rvm -v       ---> 1.8.1
gem -v       ---> 1.6.2
bundle -v    ---> Bundler version 1.0.18
```

After this `rvm implode`:

- I installed again the 2 rubies
- I created a gemset for a ree-1.8.7 app and installed the gems required -> no problem
- I created a gemset for a ruby-1.9.2 app and installed the gems through Bundle -> **no problem, even for the gems with native extensions**
- I created a gemset for another ruby-1.9.2, tried to install the gems through Bundle... **here it comes again!**

This is what I get know when performing `bundle install` (logged in as root):

```
Updating https://github.com/p7r/will_paginate.git
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Installing rake (0.9.2) 
Installing multi_json (1.0.3) 
Installing activesupport (3.1.0) 
Installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.0) with native extensions /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:552:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

        /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb 

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@app/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@app/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.0/ext/mri/gem_make.out

    [ removed the backtrace ]
```

However, if i just use `gem install bcrypt`, the gem install correctly, and I can just use `bundle install` which will run until the next gem with native extensions...

I've had the same issue with a ruby-1.9.2-p180 install, I tried downgrading RubyGems to different versions until 1.5.3, I imploded my RVM... I've looked a lot on the web for answers, this problem seems recurrent, but nothing worked for me.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What's happen when you try a simple : gem install bcrypt-ruby ?

Comment: and what does the log file `/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@app/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.0/ext/mri/gem_make.out` contain?

Comment: `gem install bcrypt` works, as any `gem install` for the gems with native extensions that bundle can't install by itself. So I can reach my objective by hand, but it's not pretty easy for automating deployment...

Comment: Well, it's really a tricky issue... I just created a new gemset to reproduce the issue. Bundle almost installed all the gems, but it finally run into the issue again on unicorn, one of the last... Same error message, and the content of the file does not help much: `/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb`

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue.  Have you found a resolution?

Comment: Well no, sorry... This kind of discouraged me, and I moved to the Ubuntu distribution, which is far more used and documented, which is better for the non-expert I am! I'm using it for several servers for some months now, and I got no issue. I'm doing OK with this ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might be due to insufficient memory for compiling the native extensions.  In my experience, `bundle install` is more memory intensive than simply using `gem install`.  Take a look at `/var/log/messages` and see if any such issues are present.  Also, use `top` to identify any heavyweight processes, like colleagues leaving `rails console` running in a screen session.  ;)

Comment: I missed your answer. It seems like a good explanation, however I'm not playing on Amazon AWS AMI anymore, so I can't investigate deeper. I hope your answer may help the next ones facing this issue...

Comment: I can confirm that I needed to create a swapfile on an AMI micro instance, otherwise bundle install was failing. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: i can further confirm that a swapfile worked for my similar problem - viz. heavy c extensions failing to bundle install but succeeding to gem install. i used http://valerio.della-porta.com/node/139 as an easy guide for creating one after seeing @LeonardoConstantino's helpful comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on linux you  need to install libraries/packages before install bcrypt-ruby gem.

`sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev` //for ruby 1.8.7

or

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

or

`sudo apt-get install ruby1.9-dev` //for ruby 1.9.2

now you can install bcrypt-ruby gem with following command

```
sudo gem install bcrypt-ruby
```

Comment: Well, it's not due to dependencies, because otherwise it would say it in the error message, plus it works without a problem when I run `gem install bcrypt`. And it fails with any gem with native extensions, bcrypt is just the first one.

Comment: the bcrypt and bcrypt-ruby are not same.. bcrypt-ruby uses different libraries.

Comment: It's definitely not linked to the gem itself. Whenever `bundle install` crash, as soon as I install the gem manually with `gem install`, the next gem with native extensions will make bundle crash...